# I'm getting Error in typeof(x) : object 'ParcelArea.m2.' not found

Tags: r

I am getting this strange error {I'm getting Error in typeof(x) : object 'ParcelArea.m2.' not found } even though I see the variable name in my dataframe.

```
> names(Cadastral)
 [1] "CadastralZoneNameAB"       "CadastralZoneCode"         "ParcelCadastralNumber"    
 [4] "Urban_Rural"               "ParcelArea.m2."            "LandType"                 
 [7] "ParcelLocalityName"        "ParcelCadastralObjectName" "ParcelAddressText"        
[10] "CultureNumber"             "ParcelsCurrentUse"         "CultureArea.m2."          
[13] "ParcelTypeOfUse"           "IsNatural"                 "Name"                     
[16] "FirstName"                 "FatherName"                "IDCode"                   
[19] "IDType"                    "MunicipalityName"          "HouseNumber"              
[22] "PersonAddressDescription"  "SharedQuotaPercentage"     "SharedQuotaNumerator"     
[25] "SharedQuotaDenominator"

LOOK at the variable 5 "ParcelArea.m2."

Code I'm using is:
 > Cadastral%>% group_by(CadastralZoneNameAB,ParcelTypeOfUse)%>% 
+   +   summarise(ParcelArea.m2.=sum(ParcelArea.m2.))
Error in typeof(x) : object 'ParcelArea.m2.' not found
```

It is worth mentioning that, yesterday this same code worked at this particular dataset. Why I'm getting this error today is frustrated?

See the yesterdays code and the output:

```
> Cadastral%>% group_by(CadastralZoneNameAB,ParcelTypeOfUse)%>% 
+   summarise(ParcelArea.m2=sum(ParcelArea.m2.))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   CadastralZoneNameAB [?]
  CadastralZoneNameAB ParcelTypeOfUse ParcelArea.m2
               <fctr>          <fctr>         <int>
1             HAJVALI       Bujqësore           608
2             MATIÇAN       Bujqësore           400
3           PRISHTINË Tokë Ndërtimore           895
```

TODAY same code, same dataset different output :(

```
> Cadastral%>% group_by(CadastralZoneNameAB,ParcelTypeOfUse)%>% 
+   +   summarise(ParcelArea.m2=sum(ParcelArea.m2.))
Error in typeof(x) : object 'ParcelArea.m2.' not found
```

Could you please help me define this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: Just a guess: could you clear the workspace (remove all variables) and try again?

Comment: I tried it but didn't work. Then I changed the code slightly and  finally come to a similar and desired output. However, still would be curios to know what was the reason for that error.